# How to get list of executing files, using awk?

Tags: command-line

I need to output all executing files in terminal. But I don't know hot to output with using `awk`(I used Linux Mint)

I used this in standart terminal:

```
du -a; find . -executable; find / -perm /a=x.
```

I used all of these commands with awk, but they didn't give me what I needed. All above commands works normal and outputs correctly.

How can I do it with awk?

Comment: *executing* and *executable* are different things - what are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: To output all executable files. With com/exe/bat extension

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing `awk` being used in the example that you posted. That said, the *simplest* way to do this would be with `find`:

```
find /path/to/files -executable -type f
```

This would give you a list that looks something like this:

```
~$ find /home/jason -executable -type f
/home/jason/checkspace.sh
/home/jason/setTargetMask.sh
/home/jason/db_backup.sh
```

If you *must* use `awk` (for a school assignment or whatever), then something like this will give you the exact same output as above:

```
for i in `ls -l | awk '{ if ( $1 ~ /x/ ) {print $NF}}'`; do echo `pwd`/$i; done
```

Comment: No, I typed this in terminal, but output is just a list of defeult folders

Comment: Your comment makes no sense. Please describe what it is that you're doing and or seeing with actionable information. Otherwise, it will be unlikely that someone can offer assistance.

Comment: Your comman with awk outputs only folder names, but NOT names of all executable files, like du -a

Comment: The command with `awk` lists files *exactly* the same way as the `find` command above it. I said as much, and the code was tested before being written as an answer. If you expect results in a particular format, perhaps you can include examples and details in your question? Mind you, if you are not using Ubuntu Linux, then there is nothing I can do for you.

Comment: Oh, I used Linux Mint...That's why it not working...